# Configuring and running PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I'm trying to generate a word template out based on the sample example of [PHPWord example](http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation). But there is no word template being generated or unable to display the page successfully. I have already filtered out the sample code and only add one section of hello world!

```
Code:
<?php
  require_once 'PHPWord.php';
  $PHPWord = new PHPWord();
  $section = $PHPWord->createSection();
  $section->addText('Hello world!');
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=helloWorld.docx");
  header("Content-Type: application/docx");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
  $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
  ?>
```

Kindly advise and if i use objwriter->save that helloworld.docx. Would it automatically be in the my web server? Or temp folder?

Thanks!

Comment: The file will be created in the current working directory where your script is running

Comment: ok. Any idea why my web page cant load ? will it show a download icon ?

Comment: No it won't show a download icon, nor is there any output to the browser in your code (aside from the headers). This will simply execute and write the file to the server's disk... the headers are meaningless. If you want to send output to the browser, use the headers "as is" but change the filename in the save() call to php://output

Answer (score 0):

If you want your web page to force the generated document to be downloaded, just use the following:

```
$PHPWord->save('helloWorld.docx', 'Word2007', true);
```